# Focused value when clicking on selectList in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, jquery

I am using selectList tag in my visualforce page, this selectList contains years number (2001,2002,...,2020) as follows:

```
<apex:selectList id="mySelect" styleClass="form_field flex_grow" required="true" multiselect="false" size="1" label="Type"  value="{!selectedYear}">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Years}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

The values of year comes from a method from the controller (it is already populated). The first item appears on the selectList is 2001

What I want to do is when I click the selectList to display years values I want the focused value in the list not to be 2001 but 2010 ( once i click the selectList to display list of years i want the focused value to be 2010).

Here is the source code I have implemented but it doesn't work:

```
$('#mySelect').focus(function(){

    if($(this).data('focused') !==  true)
    {
        $(this).data('focused',true);  
        $(this).find('option[value="2010"]').prop('selected',true);
    }

});

$('#mySelect').blur(function(){
   $(this).data('focused',false); 
});
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: If this helped can you please mark my answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code jquery code to read like this.

```
jQuery('[id$=mySelect]').focus(function() {
    if($(this).data('focused') !==  true)
    {
        $(this).data('focused',true);  
        $(this).find('option[value="2010"]').prop('selected',true);
    }
});

jQuery('[id$=mySelect').blur(function(){
    $(this).data('focused',false); 
});
```

Also below is a link that will help with other jquery development needs. It might help with more standard tips and tricks then what I added.
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Developing_Apps_with_jQuery